# How to make SVG break aspect ratio

Tags: svg

I have and SVG and I need to fulfil the browser windows. It´s an  with sag assigned to src attribute. No mather I do, always keep aspect ratio. I even force image width and height via CSS but I can´t make it work.

The url: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/814218/svg/svg_test.html

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I find the solution by recommendation of #SVG IRC Mozilla Group. The related info is here: http://codepen.io/jonitrythall/blog/preserveaspectratio-in-svg

I need to use, viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes. That´s the solution.

Here the final sample SVG source code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1282 802" preserveAspectRatio="defer none"
xml:space="preserve">
<polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#FF00FF" stroke="#93278F" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="-1.5,0 -1.5,800 638.5,400 "/>
<polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#009245" points="0,801 1280,801 640,401 "/>
<polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFF00" stroke="#FFFF00" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="638.5,400 1278.5,800 1278.5,0 "/>
</svg>`

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"` worked for me. Thanks for the steer in the right direction.

Comment: If you have width and height attributes set on the svg tag these also need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
.autoHeight{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#bg img {
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

And your html should looks like:

```
    <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
        <div id="bg" class="autoHeight" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <img class="autoHeight" src="triangles.svg" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        </div>
</body>
```

But, basically, you need use: for both, width and height: 100%

Comment: Thanks MrMins, I comment to Nikolay above I found and publish the solution. Was an SVG code issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need something like this?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
 html, body, img#svg { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; margin: 0; padding:0 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <img id="svg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/814218/svg/triangles.svg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolay but the issue was in the SVG code, not in HTML, CSS code. I finally solved. Thanks anyway. I post the solution below.